# In TextMate is there an easy way to swap two comma-separated values?

Tags: text, textmate, textmatebundles, csv

Let's say I have the following:

```
['cart', 'horse']
```

Is there a quick way to swap the two so I have the following:

```
['horse', 'cart']
```

I'm referring to the actual text and not reordering an array programmatically. For example, I usually do something like this:

1. Highlight and cut " 'horse'"
2. Delete the trailing comma
3. Paste " 'horse'" before "'cart'"
4. Delete the leading space
5. Add ", " after "'horse'"

I find myself needing to do this type of thing frequently, so I'm wondering if TextMate has some type of built-in functionality/bundle for accomplishing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Brilliant selection of example case.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it would emphasize the point :)

Comment: do you have many rows like this--is that your motivation to simplify/automate this task?  If so, TM has an excellent "column-select" function, so that e.g., you can do steps 1-5 only one but have it apply to all other rows below.

Comment: Thanks, @doug. I'm aware of this (option key), but in this case the motivation is to simplify the steps listed regardless of the number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have to do something like this, I will use regular expressions in the Search & Replace dialog.

Search for: `'(.*)', '(.*)'`

Replace with: `'$2', '$1'`

And make sure that the "Regular Expression" box is ticked. There may be a bundle that can help out with this, but I often find it easier to write a quick regex to reorder/rearrange.

Comment: Thanks, @Bill. After highlighting two values to swap I was able to record a macro with the following steps: [1] Opened the Find dialog box. [2] Used "(.*), (.*)" as the search term (without quotes), "$2, $1" as the replace term (without quotes), and checked "Regular Expression" [3] Clicked "Replace". I then saved the macro and assigned a keyboard shortcut. Works like a charm!